# Batch file code to move and rename file at the same time

Tags: batch-file

I have written following code that move's all files from one folder to another. But when I run this I get an error. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
SET today=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%%TIME:~9,2%
SET today=%today: =0%
if exist D\Instrument_Files (
    Move "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Logs\Test Exports\*.*" "D\Instrument_Files\*_%DateNtime%.csv"
) 
pause
```

Can someone please help ? Thanks

Comment: You might need a loop: `for %%I in (C:\Users\Public\Documents\Logs\Test Exports\*.*) do move %%I D\Instrument_Files\%%~nI_%today%.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The move command can only have one destination.  If it is a directory then multiple source files can be listed.  But, in your case, you want to rename each file so you need one move command for each file.  And that means you need a loop:

```
SET today=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%%TIME:~9,2%
SET today=%today: =0%
if exist "D:\Instrument_Files" (
    for %%I in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Logs\Test Exports\*.*") do move %%I "D:\Instrument_Files\%%~nI_%today%.csv"
) 
pause
```

Where `%%I` is the whole filespec and `%%~nI` is just the filename itself.

Comment: I have fixed some items in your code. I can also say that you do not need the parenthesized code block, but that is not for me to decide, just putting it out there. you can also do the for loop as:

Comment: __line 3__. `if not exist "D:\Instrument_Files" goto :eof`

Comment: __line 4.__ `for %%I in ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Logs\Test Exports\*.*") do move %%I "D:\Instrument_Files\%%~nI_%today%.csv"`

Comment: @Gerhard  Thanks for the help.  I had copied and pasted all the code except the for loop directly from the question assuming that he had tested his code - that was rather naive of me.  I think you are right about the parenthesized code block but I try to make the minimal number of changes to make it work so that it's obvious what changes actually answer the question.